# how to tell what's writing to my hdd?

Tags: hard-drive, disk-usage

This morning I deleted some stuff, moved stuff etc and ended up with 1.3gb free space on my hard drive when me and the kids went to a trampoline park for an hour or so. I noticed when we got home my hard drive was down to 850mb of free space so something filled up ~500mb in just over an hour so I'm curious is there a way to see what has been written to my hard drive recently?

I'm running Xubuntu 22.04 currently. Thank you for any help with this.

edit: I just ran `sudo journalctl --vacuum-size=10M` and freed up 488mb from /var/log/journal/

I have SystemMaxUse set to 50mb in the config file so I'm not sure why it would have written 488mb.

Comment: thank you. I ran that and this is a random bit of it so I guess firefox is creating quite a stir. i emptied the cache but it definitely wasn't 500mb 
`/home/david/snap/firefox/common/.cache/mozilla/firefox/8ivmjj8f.default/safebrowsing/mozplugin-block-digest256.sbstore
/home/david/snap/firefox/common/.cache/mozilla/firefox/8ivmjj8f.default/safebrowsing/mozplugin-block-digest256.vlpset
/home/david/snap/firefox/common/.cache/mozilla/firefox/8ivmjj8f.default/safebrowsing/except-flashallow-digest256.vlpset`

Comment: I would try `sudo apt install iotop` and then `sudo iotop -o`

Comment: Thanks, I ran iotop -o and everything was writing to journal so i vaccumed again and I just freed another 736mb from journal. how do i stop it from writing literally gigabytes every day? Can I turn off writing to journal altogether?

Comment: I don't think it should be that big, `du -sh /var/log/journal/* | sort -h` and see which file is causing the problem, then `tail -f /path/to/thatfile.log` and see if there's continuous errors/messages

Comment: ok, i ran du -sh /var/log/journal/* | sort -h and got ``` 97M /var/log/journal/b605132c10d046d5b33df013853acefa ```  but running ```tail -f /var/log/journal/b605132c10d046d5b33df013853acefa.log``` gives ```tail: cannot open '/var/log/journal/b605132c10d046d5b33df013853acefa.log' for reading: No such file or directory
``` but inside that folder is a system.journal file and user-1000.journal that's 8mb.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sudo find / -mmin -60 -type f -iname "*" -not -path "/proc/*" -not -path "/sys/*"`